# google maps map style

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

is there a possibility to have the map exactly like Google Maps Android app does ? I mean with the yellow roads etc. Using google maps api for android we have only hybrid, normal, satellite and no one looks like the app one. I tried the styling wizard, the one i need is the standard one from wizard, but nothing is generated as ROADMAP is the standard style.

Answer (score 2):

You can style the Map View / Map Fragment to however you want
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling

Use the Map Style Wizard https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ to create a style that matches the one you are looking at and apply that to your codebase (using the instructions above)